# How can I send and receive data to a serial port or USB port in ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, usb, serial-port, libusb

I am developing a web application for a parking. I want to control a gateway entrance with a device connected to USB port, but we know that the browser is in a [sandbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_(computer_security)), so there isn't any access to the computer's port.

I searched the web and found out there is some possibility to do so via [ActiveX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveX) and/or [Java applets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_applet), but I'm a novice to these things and want a complete tutorial or a wiki book that describe it or even class libraries relative to.

I want to send data to a USB or COM port via an ASP.NET application (client side). I know that browsers aren't able to do so because of security issues. What would be an example of using ActiveX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to host an ASP.NET *application/website on a server*. Your browser is on a client machine. Your client will request a page from the server and *the website could not be hosted on the client machine*.

So you can connect your device to a server machine and the client sends you request to post data through a device, e.g. a GSM modem. Now you need to connect your device to the server and you can make a [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows) service to pull the posted message from the database to post them through the device.

You need to talk to a COM port. Even your USB devices listen to a COM port. You can use the serial port class to communicate with the device. You can do this with a desktop application and *I could not see any reason for using a website*. The following links will help you.

- **[COM port listening](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/75770/Basic-serial-port-listening-application)**
- **[Serial port](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx)**

Comment: Hummm , You are right i should connect device to server but i want that when a parking costumer is standing in front of entrance gate way

Comment: Ok , You are right i should connect device to server but i want that when a parking costumer is standing in front of entrance gate way it opens automatically by checking it's number via a camera and setting a switch enable to open it

Comment: I need a complete example of writing data on usb port/lpt1/com in asp.net and a complete example to create an activeX that does the following and uses it's functions...